# Button to launch form in modal

Tags: sharepoint-designer

What I want to do is place a button on a page in our SP2010 Enterprise environment that once clicked launches a custom form (for a payments list) in a modal window. I have done this in SPD 2010 within a custom page using an asp button and a html button control but I was hoping to use an OOB web part that I can place a button in.
I am not a developer so cannot use VS etc.
Thanks

Comment: For OOTB web parts the options to open e.g. links in dialog (=modal) are highly restricted. I wonder if you could use a CEWP with small script & HTML button for this, such as this one: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57946/how-to-open-a-form-in-a-modal-dialog-popup-using-c

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94181/model-popup-in-sharepoint-2010